# How can I implement a native image viewer with pinch to zoom in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

For quite a long time I have been trying to get a "native" image viewer into my Xamarin app.

When I say native, I mean rendered natively, but also behaving how you would expect an image in the phones app gallery to behave.  I have an Xamarin Forms app that targets iOS, UWP and Android, and I don't mind writing custom implementations for each platform to facilitate this.

The image in the app should:

- Pinch and pan the same way a photo in a gallery would do
- "Spring back" if over-zoomed, or scaled out too far

So basically, just behave how an image would in a photo gallery on a device.

Despite there being a tonne of apps out there that implement this functionality on Android, I've yet to find an implementation that would accomplish this.  I have attempted the following

- Use something like https://github.com/TBertuzzi/Xamarin.Forms.PinchZoomImage which works, but pans weirdly, and doesn't "spring back" when overzoomed.  It also don't pan correctly when two fingers are used (I know that these issues are probably because this library works across iOS/UWP/Android platforms, thus it would be impractical to take advantage of native functionality 100% on every platform).
- Tried to load Android native components through Visual Studio via using AAR binding creation (as at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) and using a native Android library to accomplish the task.  This flat out didn't work - the produced bindings weren't usable.

For a simple problem, I feel that I'm missing something for sure.

**Using Xamarin.Forms, how can I implement a pinch to zoom for pictures on Android that behave the way a native image viewer would?**

Comment: Agreed, this is a pretty big gap in the 3rd party controls market and I'm not sure why nobody has filled it yet. There are editors, but not just a simple viewer (nor is there a nice simple 3rd party gallery control).

Comment: Well, at least if I make one, I won't have to worry that I've re-invented the wheel.

Comment: Well if you do, definitely share it, however rough. Seems like something to community would like to add to.